# How can I open a url from hyperlink on existing silverlight container on same page

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer, silverlight

I have a page in aspx which contains hyperlinks and div container which contains silverlight window.

I am trying to open new URL through hyperlink element in asp/html. Is it possible?

I notice that in existing application html/asp hyperlinks are opening up new tab on silverlight container. (windowless attribute is set to false).

Any help or guidance is highly appreciated. Thank you. (I have no experience in silverlight applications)

[image]

This is what I have. Yellow box is HTML images as hyperlinks and red marked container is div holding silverlight element. OnClick of home and folder icon new tabs are getting opened in additional tabs on same container. I am adding new hyperlink icons and want to open it in similar fashion in new tab.

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" id="silverlightControl">

    </object>
    <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; display: none; height: 0px; width: 0px;
        border: 0px"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the difference is between what you want to do and what the existing application does. Do you want to add new links that do the same as `Home` and `Folder`? And, if so, can't you use the same technique and code as these two links?

Comment: yes you are right i am trying to replicate home n folder behavior. code for home and folder is in dll so i am unable to see or modify that. from my analysis what i need is to add new `tabitem` to same `tabcontrol` / silverlight `object`. since i cant change the backend i am trying to figure out if it can be achieved through JS

Comment: The Silverlight application does its own rendering, using its own controls. It does not create HTML elements (like ASP.NET WebForms do, for example). You can call functions of your Silverlight application from the Javascript code if these functions have been made available in the application code. If that is the case for `Home` and `Folder`, you should see it in the Javascript code called by the two existing links, and you could follow the same path. Can we see the markup for the hyperlinks, and their event handlers (in client code) if they have any?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks for your time. I followed HTML Bridge functions coded in JS to call Silverlight functions. It worked for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Calling [System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(System.Uri)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190502(v=vs.95).aspx) will open the specified page in the current browser.

```
string link = "http://some_Url_here";
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(link));
```

Comment: I have edited my question with added information with image. If you could guide more on it. I need to open new URL in same container in new tab. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Based on the new information, my answer is wrong. I misunderstood what you were asking.

Comment: Is there anything I could do to achieve this? I also added code for silverlight object which in wrapped in div followed by iframe.

Comment: That is outside of my knowledge set. Would require some research.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help on it. :)